# HTTP verb for "splitting" a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I am working on a Ruby on Rails endpoint / controller action that "splits" a record into two different new records.

This endpoint will:
1. Destroy a existing record
2. Create two new records

What HTTP verb should this be? (post,delete,patch,put, etc.)?
I know it's definitely not a get but I'm not sure what the convention is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: delete http verb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope have understood your question

First you must have declare a route to the action delete from the first record

```
delete "/records/:id",  to: '/records#destroy'
```

inside the record controller you create the action delete and there create the records that you like with the data you like

```
class RecordsController < ApplicationController

  #DELETE /records/:id
  def destroy
    @record = @record.destroy

    @record1 = Record.new()
    @record2 = Record.new()

  end   
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you can use `GET` request for your delete or update action, but in the real world, it is not good idea to use it.

So, your endpoint should see like this

```
delete '/this/endpoint/will/delete/your/record', to: 'magic#foo'
post '/this/endpoint/will/create/a/record', to: 'magic#bar'
```

You can find more routing stuff in this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thanks for your response.

But this is a single controller action (single endpoint), not two separte ones

Comment: @chrishyunhokim , could you explain bit more because I though, you just wanted to use 1 controller. On the other hand, maybe you can find something in the guide.